# Open Arena Game Crash Upon Setting Up Game

Tags: games, crash

OpenArena is a quake-like game. This Game is crashing upon beginning a fight within the game. Character models can be loaded, as seen within the character options.

Seems like some important stuff but I dunno:
 The text in the terminal when the game crashes-

```
  ----- Client Shutdown (Received signal 11) -----
 RE_Shutdown( 1 )
 OpenAL capture device closed.
 -----------------------
 ----- Server Shutdown (Received signal 11) -----
 tty]Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The weird Quake 3 symbol in the launch menu-

[image]

This is all I could gather.

Comment: It seems that a bug has already been reported a year ago for this error: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openarena/+bug/1651561

Answer (score 2):

Try to download Open Arena from their site http://www.openarena.ws/download.php?view.4
Unzip file and run openarena.x86_64
Downloaded version (0.8.8) works fine on my computer, while open arena from ubuntu repository have same bug.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems the package in the apt repository is broken.

Try the flatpak version:

```
flatpak install flathub ws.openarena.OpenArena
```